# Find maximum of previous rows in DataFrame without taking current row into consideration

Tags: python, dataframe, max

I am trying to create a new column which calculates the percentage change (both positive and negative) of the current value to the previous maximum of the value (i.e. max draw down and max run up (mdd/mru):

Suppose I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [1000, 1100,np.nan, 1050, 990,np.nan, 1200,np.nan, 1150, 1300]})

    Value
0   1000.0
1   1100.0
2   NaN
3   1050.0
4   990.0
5   NaN
6   1200.0
7   NaN
8   1150.0
9   1300.0
```

I am looking for the following result:

```
   Value  mdd/mru 
0   1000   0.0000
1   1100   0.1000
2    NaN      NaN
3   1050  -0.0454 
4    990  -0.1000
5    NaN      NaN 
6   1200   0.0909
7    NaN      NaN
8   1150  -0.0417  
9   1300   0.0832
```

This is my current line:

`df['mdd/mru'] = (df['Value']-(df['Value'].cummax()))/df['Value'].cummax()`

However, this takes the current row value into consideration, creating the following result

```
    Value   mdd/mru
0   1000.0  0.000000
1   1100.0  0.000000
2   NaN     0.000000
3   1050.0  -0.045455
4   990.0   -0.100000
5   NaN     0.000000
6   1200.0  0.000000
7   NaN     0.000000
8   1150.0  -0.041667
9   1300.0  0.000000


adding .shift(1) as Bhargav suggested produces the following (wrong) result:


Value   mdd/mru
0   1000.0  NaN
1   1100.0  0.100000
2   NaN     NaN
3   1050.0  NaN
4   990.0   -0.100000
5   NaN     NaN
6   1200.0  NaN
7   NaN     NaN
8   1150.0  NaN
9   1300.0  0.083333

Replacing NaN with 0 before adding new column returns:

df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
df['mdd/mru'] =  ((df['Value']-(df['Value'].shift(1).cummax()))/df['Value'].shift(1).cummax()).fillna(0)
 

Value   mdd/mru
0   1000.0  0.000000
1   1100.0  0.100000
2   0.0    -1.000000
3   1050.0  -0.045455
4   990.0   -0.100000
5   0.0    -1.000000
6   1200.0  0.090909
7   0.0    -1.000000
8   1150.0 -0.041667
9   1300.0  0.083333
```

While one could now replace 0.00 and -1 with NaN again, I am wondering if there is a "cleaner" solution?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about uisng [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)

```
df['mdd/mru'] =  ((df['Value']-(df['Value'].shift(1).cummax()))/df['Value'].shift(1).cummax()).fillna(0)
```

output #

```
Value   mdd/mru
0   1000  0.000000
1   1100  0.100000
2   1050 -0.045455
3    990 -0.100000
4   1200  0.090909
5   1150 -0.041667
6   1300  0.083333
```

Comment: Good shout, tahnks! I have tried .shift() as well before and it works on the small example given here but on the larger dataset for some reason it does not. The larger dataset has NaN values in there (on purpose) - maybe that affects it?

Comment: Yeah try filling Nan with zeros & Try again @rose_1 if deon't works pls, Let me know

Comment: It's not the "cleanest" of solutions I think, although it should theoretically work. 1. Change DF to:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': [1000, 1100,np.nan, 1050, 990,np.nan, 1200,np.nan, 1150, 1300]})
2. let's replace NaN: df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
3. add new column: df['mdd/mru'] =  ((df['Value']-(df['Value'].shift(1).cummax()))/df['Value'].shift(1).cummax()).fillna(0)

returns: 

Value mdd/mru
0 1000.0 0.000000
1 1100.0 0.100000
2 0.0 -1.000000
3 1050.0 -0.045455
4 990.0 -0.100000
5 0.0 -1.000000
6 1200.0 0.090909
7 0.0 -1.000000
8 1150.0 -0.041667
9 1300.0 0.083333

Comment: I suppose I could now go and replace 0 and -1 with NaN again but that would risk falsifying data where the value of 'Value' actually happened to be the same as the previous highest value. What do you think?